# Get the minimum value if not null in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, min

I am trying to get the minimum Value from G2 to G101, only if the value is not null. I found different methods but none of them is working with me. I tried :

```
=MIN(IF(G2:G101>0,G2:G101))
=SMALL(G2:G101,COUNTIF($G$1:$G$101,0)+1)
```

I alwayse get the message : `The formula you typed contain an error`

Comment: Maybe field separator in your system is `;` not `,`.

Comment: If you copied those formulas from a web page, they may have interim special characters like non-breaking spaces or even zero-width spaces inserted to discourage copying directly to a worksheet. Retype them manually into a new cell and try again.

Comment: @BrakNicku You are right, I have to use ; and not , thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need the **array formula**:

```
=MIN(IF(G2:G101>0,G2:G101))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: I tried ctr+shift+enter and I get the same problem. I am using Mac Os